# I'm trying to train the code of Target-Aware Deep Tracking in matlab

Tags: matlab, matconvnet

I'm for now compiling in CPU version.I am working on matlab 2020a.I've tried to remove the vl_nnconv.m from matconvnet but i still get the following error.
Also the matconvnet i'm using is version matconvnet-1.0-beta25 I'm stuck here since 2 days ,could somebody lease help me out with this issue?

https://github.com/XinLi-zn/TADT
The above is the github code i'm trying to work on.
Foloowing are the errors i'm getting:

```
Error using vl_nnconv
The option name is not a string (argument number 5)

Error in dagnn.Conv/forward (line 11)
      outputs{1} = vl_nnconv(...

Error in dagnn.Layer/forwardAdvanced (line 85)
      outputs = obj.forward(inputs, {net.params(par).value}) ;

Error in dagnn.DagNN/eval (line 91)
  obj.layers(l).block.forwardAdvanced(obj.layers(l)) ;

Error in get_subwindow_feature (line 37)
    net_feat.eval({'input',gpuArray(patch_sw)});

Error in tadt_tracking (line 63)
   feat_groups = get_subwindow_feature(net_feat, img, sw_location, input_sz, feat_layer);

Error in Demo_TADT (line 23)
[result, fps]=tadt_tracking(seq_info.img_list, seq_info.gt(1,:), vgg16_model_path, display);
```

the following are the functions that is causing the error and the argument is obj.pad

```
function outputs = forward(obj, inputs, params)
      if ~obj.hasBias, params{2} = [] ; end
      outputs{1} = vl_nnconv(...
        inputs{1}, params{1}, params{2}, ...
        'pad', obj.pad, ...
        'stride', obj.stride, ...
        obj.opts{:}) ;
    end
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JoachimSauer apologies.

Comment: @AnderBiguri vl_nnconv is a mex file